# How suspend chromedp.Submit() so javascript can update action field

Tags: go, browser, automation, chromedp

I'm attempting to use chromedp to log into a dashboard. the action on the form is `action="javascript:void(0);"`. When submit is pressed a number of JS functions kick off, with the end result producing the url; the action updated and the submit process continues.

looking at the log, chromedp is using `"javascript:void(0);"` as the action, so the process is in a continuous loop looking `app-sidebar-navigation-menu__item__label`. login() is the relevant function:

```
func login(cfg *config, url, username, password string, res *string) chromedp.Tasks {
   return chromedp.Tasks{
      chromedp.Navigate(url),
      chromedp.WaitVisible(#Email, chromedp.ByID),
      chromedp.WaitVisible(#Password, chromedp.ByID),
      chromedp.SendKeys(#Email, username, chromedp.ByID),
      chromedp.SendKeys(#Password, password, chromedp.ByID),
      chromedp.Submit(#Email, chromedp.ByID),
      chromedp.WaitVisible(.app-sidebar-navigation-menu__item__label, chromedp.BySearch),
      chromedp.Click(.app-sidebar-navigation-menu__item__label, chromedp.BySearch),
      chromedp.Text(.app-sidebar-navigation-menu__item__label, res, chromedp.BySearch),
    }
}
```

I tried to add a sleep(), but I don't think I'm using it in the correct way:

```
...

chromedp.Submit(#Email, chromedp.ByID, chromedp.After(func(i context.Context, n ...*cdp.Node) error {
chromedp.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
return nil
})),

...
```

I do plan to take a look at `chromedp.ListenTarget` to see if that's a reasonable route, but I'm hoping this is a straightforward solution (and it not, Id need some help with ListenTarget);

I also opened this as an [issue](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/665) on chromedp's github repo; still waiting on a comment.

Comment: Sleeping is almost never a solution. Still, why not try `time.Sleep()`?

Comment: I don't believe I'm using sleep [ `chromedb.Sleep()` or `time.Sleep()` ] correctly. I tried `time.Sleep(large_number)` but `chromedp.Submit()` still proceeded; using javascript:void() as the action's value...and I agree, sleeping is never the final solution but I'm grasping here to get something to work.

Comment: I migrated to [go-rod](https://github.com/go-rod/rod); which is a much, much cleaning implementation / i-face. The page functions wrap a retry until the element is visible or it times out...Got what I needed (with clear-er examples) in under 10 mins.

Comment: @lan thank you for your comment. All day i lost with chromedp, but rod so understandeble, it's treasure